# Click HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, webautomation

How do I click a button using Excel VBA?

What I have tried:

```vb
Dim button As HTMLElementCollection
Set button = htmldoc.getElementById(<buttonId>)
button.Click
```

But this seemingly does nothing. No errors no apparent changes.

I verified that the button was selected by:

```vb
Debug.Print (button)
Debug.Print (button.innerHTML)
```

which will show me [object HTMLButtonElement] and the innerHtml. When the button is manually clicked a drop down menu is expanded, but through VBA no behavior is observed.

Comment: If it's excel then it's VBA.

Comment: @CruleD Not necessarily. I used vb.net alot to interact with excel

Comment: Elliot if when you click the button a dropdown menu is expanded, that's the problem. the WebBrowser is not able to call java scripts or any other script on the page.

Comment: @Simo, I suspected that the java script might be the problem.. Is there perhaps a way for VBA to fire a js event? more specifically a click event related to a specific html element.

Comment: There is a webbrowser for vba that has css and js engine

Comment: @Simo : While it's perfectly possible to interact with Excel from VB.NET, the `Set` keyword gives it away: This is VBA. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent never used and probably i will never use vba, not familiar with the syntax

Comment: @Simo : No worries. It's just that `Set <variable> = <value>` doesn't work in VB.NET.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah I know it, but i wasn't paying too mucn attention on the syntax while my efforts were on the problem itself

Comment: 1) Is it vba? Or vb.net?   2) Please include the relevant HTML using the snippet tool via [edit] so we can copy paste for potential testing 3) Include URL where possible 4) Include your coding efforts so far 5) Confirm whether an answer using selenium basic (VBA) is acceptable

Comment: "When the button is manually clicked a drop down menu is expanded" - then the browser is able to process what ever mechanism that generates the drop-down.  Are you certain that you retrieved the proper button element? "I suspected that the java script might be the problem" - Why, do you receive the script error dialog?  How are you creating the browser? Is it the Userform Webbrowser control or did you create an instance of `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`?  If it is the userform control, then you are likely having version emulation issues.  This can be corrected with a registry setting.

Comment: You can also use a utility website like [https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/) to see how the browser is reporting itself.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: My current working theory is that the button I am targeting is actually not the object that click events are listened for. perhaps one of the surrounding elements or sub elements is what needs to be clicked on. When you do this manually whatever element needs to be clicked is probably invisible and laying on top or below the button element and thus detects the event.

Comment: I was in the process of writing a script to click on every node in the DOM to see what ones triggered some behavior when I received word that the whole web automation aspect of this project is being scrapped.. So I have now moved on from this, having never solved the problem. I think I would have cracked it though by eventually looping through the DOM like I said, and narrowing down the behavior to a specific element.

Comment: The problem then was simply that the html/js I was looking at was obviously generated by some framework and it was difficult to follow the logic to determine exactly what element needed to be click on to get the behavior I expected. I did not have access to the original source code of the page, which would have made a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the button is well selected and it does fire the `.click` event.

Unfortunately the standard `WebBrowser` for VBA uses an old Internet Explorer browser and it doesn't support JS, CSS, ecc...

I suggest you too look for other WebBrowser, for example [GeckoFX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Gecko_SDK).

It might work in order to solve your problem. Online you can found alot of tutorial for `GeckoFX` in VBA.